# Access the user input/utterance from Lex in python Lambda function

Tags: python, lambda, aws-lambda, amazon-lex

I am looking for a way to access the actual question which the user asked ( or the utterance) on Lex in the python Lambda function code. When I print the `event` parameter in `lambda_handler(event, context)` I see the following getting printed:

```
input_request={'messageVersion': '1.0', 'invocationSource': 'FulfillmentCodeHook', 'userId': 'user1', 'sessionAttributes': None, 'bot': {'name': 'bot_name', 'alias': None, 'version': '$LATEST'}, 'outputDialogMode': 'Text', 'currentIntent': {'name': 'bo1', 'slots': {'Time': '10:00','Date': '2017-06-20'}, 'confirmationStatus': 'Confirmed'}, 'inputTranscript': 'yes'}
```

I do not see any option to access the actual question that the user asked or even the utterance that matched that particular question. Is there a way to do it in case I am missing it?

Answer (score 5):

I can confirm ddperdue answer, inputTranscript holds the utterance

so you can extract it from

> event['inputTranscript']

Answer (score 3):

The user's utterance can be found in the `inputTranscript` key. In the example you have posted it is 'yes'.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create slot types and intents. Only then can `currentIntent` be filled with user input/utterance.

The event input format doesn't have the utterance at this time.

You can get a [list of utterances to your bot](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/LexModelBuildingService.html#getUtterancesView-property) and process that for the latest utterance for a slot type.

Reference:

- [Building Lex bots](https://github.com/awslabs/amz-ai-building-better-bots)
- [Event input format](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lex/latest/dg/lambda-input-response-format.html)

Comment: I have created `intents` and `slots` on `Lex` console and in my `currentIntent` all I get is intent name and slot-names and values. I do not see the utterances or the initial question that triggered this intent. In my post above I have updated to show what get in my `currentIntent`